# How to find average of different objects in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Everyone,

I am struggling to write a JS function that would return average values for my array of objects.

Here is my array

```
    const array = [
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-05",
        value: 0.2
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-05",
        value: 0.2
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-05",
        value: 1
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-06",
        value: 0.2
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-06",
        value: 0.3
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-06",
        value: 0.8
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-07",
        value: 0.7
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-07",
        value: 0.7
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-08",
        value: 0.7
      },
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-08",
        value: 0.2
      }, 
      {
        createdAt: "2021-06-08",
        value: 0.9  
      }
      
    ]
```

And want I want to get is

```
const newArray = [

{
    createdAt: "2021-06-05",
    value: 0.467
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-06",
    value: 0.433
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-07",
    value: 0.7
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-08",
    value: 0.6
  },

]
```

I tried using array.map here in codePen and it works to certain degree but not really:

https://codepen.io/klimenko3007/pen/PopaMZz?editors=0011

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

`map` does not change the length of resulting array. So it won't really work. You need `reduce` to change the structure.

You have 2 separate tasks here

- Group items by some key (created date)
- Find average in group

Not the shortest code but it does clear things and works.

```js
const array = JSON.parse(`[{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-05\",\"value\":0.2},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-05\",\"value\":0.2},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-05\",\"value\":1},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-06\",\"value\":0.2},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-06\",\"value\":0.3},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-06\",\"value\":0.8},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-07\",\"value\":0.7},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-07\",\"value\":0.7},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-08\",\"value\":0.7},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-08\",\"value\":0.2},{\"createdAt\":\"2021-06-08\",\"value\":0.9}]`)


function averageByDate(data) {
  const groups = data.reduce((map, record) => {
    const { createdAt, value } = record;
    
    if (map.has(createdAt)) {
      map.set(createdAt, map.get(createdAt).concat(value));
    } else {
      map.set(createdAt, [value])
    }
    
    return map
  }, new Map())
  
  const average = [...groups.entries()].map(([createdAt, values]) => {
    return {
      createdAt,
      value: values.reduce((a, b) => a + b)/values.length
    }
  })
  
  return average
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(averageByDate(array)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-05",
    value: 0.2
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-05",
    value: 0.2
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-05",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-06",
    value: 0.2
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-06",
    value: 0.3
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-06",
    value: 0.8
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-07",
    value: 0.7
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-07",
    value: 0.7
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-08",
    value: 0.7
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-08",
    value: 0.2
  }, 
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-08",
    value: 0.9  
  }
  
]

let grouped = array.reduce((grouped, {createdAt, value}) => ({
  ...grouped,
  [createdAt]: grouped[createdAt] 
                 ? [...grouped[createdAt], value] 
                 : [value]
}), {})

let result = Object.entries(grouped).map(([createdAt, values]) => ({
  createdAt,
  value: values.reduce((summ, value) => summ + value, 0) / values.length
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

First build an object with keys as "date" and value as arr of accumalated values for that date.

Use `Object.entries` and `map` to get array of objects with avg calculation.

```js
const avg = (arr) => {
  const all = {};
  arr.forEach(({ createdAt, value }) => (all[createdAt] ??= []).push(value));
  return Object.entries(all).map(([createdAt, arr]) => ({
    createdAt,
    value: arr.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val) / arr.length,
  }));
};

const array = [
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-05",
    value: 0.2,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-05",
    value: 0.2,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-05",
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-06",
    value: 0.2,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-06",
    value: 0.3,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-06",
    value: 0.8,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-07",
    value: 0.7,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-07",
    value: 0.7,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-08",
    value: 0.7,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-08",
    value: 0.2,
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-06-08",
    value: 0.9,
  },
];


console.log(avg(array));
```